# knockout bindinq object with foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

```
    features:[
       "attributes": {"CityName": "asdfsad", "Population":"125005"}
    ]

    features:[
       "attributes": {"FirstName": "xyz"}
    ]
    ....
```

I am getting features in javascript object and adding it in a

`queryResult =ko.observableArray()`

But as you can see the attributes are not an array. so I can not bind it with foreach binding. **features** object attributes properties are different one another.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: queryResult">
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</div>
```

This writes **[object Object]** in span element

```
<div data-bind="foreach: queryResult">
    <span data-bind="text: $data.CityName"></span>
</div>
```

This writes **asdfsad** in span element, but other feature attributes doesnot have property named **CityName**

Comment: you need to start by knowing what property you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Basically knockout foreach binding is for using with homogenous data. Also, it's not a good design if a web API returns inhomogenous collections. But if you still need this, you can hack with custom bindings, for example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.objectText = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data) {
        var myobj = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (!myobj) return;

        // dynamically extract data from the object
        var myproperty = "";
        if (myobj.CityName)
            myproperty = myobj.CityName;
        else if (myobj.FirstName)
            myproperty = myobj.FirstName;

        // if there is data, "redirect" to normal text binding
        if (myproperty)
            ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return myproperty; }, allBindingsAccessor, data);
    }
};
```

And then write your binding like:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: queryResult">
    <span data-bind="objectText: $data"></span>
</div>
```

This is quite ugly, but you can get the idea I hope. This way you can convert any object to any kind of text representation, for example you could find the first non-empty string property, or concatenate all non-empty properties with their names, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you don't care about IE<=8, try http://jsfiddle.net/7y48q/

If you want to support IE6,7,8, load underscore.js and replace Object.keys(result) with _.keys(result)

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: queryResult, as: 'result'}">
    <hr/>
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(result), as: 'k' }  -->
      <span data-bind="text: k"></span>: <span data-bind="text: result[k]"></span><br/>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is, but if you're trying to expand all the objects try the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="bindingRoot">
    <div data-bind="foreach: queryResult">
        <div data-bind="crack: $data">
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>: <span data-bind="text: value"></span><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var model = {
    queryResult: ko.observableArray()
};

model.queryResult.push({ CityName: 'asdfsad', Population: 125005 });
model.queryResult.push({ FirstName: 'xyz' });

ko.bindingHandlers.crack = {
    init: function () {
        return ko.bindingHandlers['foreach'].init.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
            cracked = [];

        for (var k in value) {
            cracked.push({ name: k, value: value[k] });
        }

        return ko.bindingHandlers['foreach'].update.apply(this, [element, function () { return cracked; }, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext]);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById('bindingRoot'));
```

Result:

```
CityName: asdfsad
Population: 125005
FirstName: xyz
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fng27/